# Hide show function not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

My test.php page is as under

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" id="hideshowone">Hide</a>
    <div id="hideshowotherone" style="padding:20px; margin:20px; border:2px solid black; width:400px; color:green;" >However, as a practical matter, you will be somewhat more limited if you want your documents to work with a variety of browsers, CSS editors, and JavaScript frameworks.
    As noted in other responses, jQuery has problems with ids that contain periods and colons.</div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using Jquery version: /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
My main.js page is as under:

```
$('#hideshowone').toggle(function(){
$('#hideshowone').text('Show');
$('#hideshowotherone').hide();
},function(){
$('#hideshowone').text('Hide');
$('#hideshowotherone').show();
});
```

I want to operate hide and show function with one single link i.e. when I press hide then paragraph should hide and link text should appear as show and when I press the link show then paragraph should appear and link text should change to hide, please help as this code is not working as paragraph appears however link disappears immediately as an when page is loaded, please help:

Comment: `toggle(fn,fn)` is deprecated. WHat version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */     this one

Comment: It doesn't exist in that version http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: test.php? I don't see php there..

Answer (score 1):

**This works fine for me. Try it out**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="hideshowone">Hide</a>
  <div id="hideshowotherone" style="padding:20px; margin:20px; border:2px solid black; width:400px; color:green;" >However, as a practical matter, you will be somewhat more limited if you want your documents to work with a variety of browsers, CSS editors, and JavaScript frameworks.
    As noted in other responses, jQuery has problems with ids that contain periods and colons.</div>


    <script>

      $("#hideshowone").click(function(){

      if($(this).text() == 'Show'){
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $("#hideshowotherone").toggle();
      } else {
        $(this).text('Show');
        $("#hideshowotherone").toggle();
      }
    });

    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**if you have any questions let me know**

Comment: your js version is different, mine is Query v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014, so its not working, can you give me code which work for this version

Comment: that's simple just replace the <script> tag source with the proper jQuery version: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

Comment: @Sidharth i've updated the code with the correct jQuery version 1.11.2. if you're still having problems let me know. the code is working fine on my end

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hideshowone').click(function(){
  $('#hideshowotherone').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hideshowone').click(function () {
        if ($('#hideshowotherone').is(':visible')) {
            $('#hideshowone').text('Show');
            $('#hideshowotherone').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('#hideshowone').text('Hide');
            $('#hideshowotherone').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle with jQuery 1.11.0](http://jsfiddle.net/8ysyq5pd/3/)

Comment: @Sidharth how do you test it because it works with jQuery 1.11.0 too. Have you tried the jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes I have tried but its not working. My version is /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

Comment: I think it's not working because you don't have it inside the `ready` event. I've updated the example.

Comment: t3chb0t When I click on the link then it is blinking but but not changing link text, also it is not hiding the paragraph

Comment: @Sidharth It's a really strange behavior which I unfortunatelly cannot explain. You need to provide more information about your environment... because I think it works for anyone else ;-) like some other examples here as well.

Comment: @t3chb0t - you only need to wrap your code into a `ready` event if you run it before the DOM was drawn. You don't need it if you call it just before your `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/j9scjd9f/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideshowone').click(function(){
$('#hideshowotherone').toggle();
        if($(this).text() == "Hide"){
$('#hideshowone').text('Show');
        }else
$('#hideshowone').text('Hide');            
        });

});
```

Comment: @Sidharth you can't get the exact working code. You have to check few things at your side. Look at the Ids and match the html if it is different.

Comment: @Superman it's a very bad idea to check the text as a condition in a case like this.

Comment: I have checked IDs these are matching, limits are also ok but still it is not working

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't think this is going to be an issue. This is all that required to achieve this functionality and trying to optimize on this level is simple a waste of time. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Sidharth You might missing the included jquery files or mismatched version of the jquery. Go to the fiddle and check the jquery version, it is 1.9.1 you can download it from jquery site and try to run the code on your system.

Comment: @Superman sorry, I don't ;-) because I have too much experience. if you want to create a mantainable code you cannot rely on a text. You should do it right at the first time.

Comment: @t3chb0t you can edit my fiddle for this text thing. I'll appreciate it. No problem.